# ¿Como mostrar un icono de carga mientras se carga otra vista en react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Tengo mis vistas ya terminadas, pero algunas deben cargar varios datos antes de poder mostrarse, por eso se nota un delay pasando de una vista a otra, quisiera que al presionar el botón que me lleva a la otra vista, muestra un icono de carga y que cuando la nueva vista cargue todos sus datos entonces si la muestre. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como lograr esto?

**De esta vista**
[image]
**Debo ir a esta**
[image]

Cabe resaltar que estoy usando para enrutacion **react-navigation**

Comment: Compartí lo que fuiste haciendo así se te puede ayudar un poco más. Y se puede mediante los manejo de `state`.

Comment: Para no recibir puntos negativos y que se te pueda ayudar más, copiá el código en vez de una imagen del código.

Comment: Esos datos que decís que tarda en mostrar son de un servidor? Porque si es así podrías hacer que te muestre el loading hasta que termine y con los `state` mostrar una cosa o la otra. [Te dejo un ejemplo de loading que encontré.](https://medium.com/@kelleyannerose/react-native-activityindicator-for-a-quick-easy-loading-animation-593c06c044dc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con el código que has compartido no puedo ofrecerte una respuesta orientada a tu proyecto, pero en resumen lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

1. En el **constructor** de la vista destino, tienes que tener una variable de estado que indique que está cargando:

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.refs = null;
     this.state = {
       loading:true,
       tablaConMisDatos:[]
     };
   }
   ```
2. En el método **componentDidMount()** o **componentWillMount()** debes hacer la llámada al método que cargue tus datos, imagínate que haces una llamada a un método que devuelve una promesa despues de hacer una consulta en un webservice:

   ```
   componentDidMount()
   {
     getMyData().then((misDatos)=>{
       this.setState({loading: false, tablaConMisDatos: misDatos});
     }).catch((err)=>{
       //mostrar algo cuando ocurra un error, lo puedes tratar aquí
       console.log(err);
       this.setState({loading: false});
     })
   }
   ```
3. Por último en tu método **render()** debes indicar que muestra otra cosa mientras está cargando, tal que así:

   ```
   render()
   {
     if(this.state.loading)
     {
       return (<Text>Cargando...</Text>);
     }

     return (
       //Tu código antiguo aquí
     )
   }
   ```

De esta forma te aseguras que solo muestre la vista una vez tengas los datos.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.